# How can I split a result from a query into two columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

In this [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BTSbVXk-_xTZ12BH3t5RKOVeD3VHl3DelXGI0kRtrS0/edit?usp=sharing) I collect data from a Google Form and output the results with a query. I need to split the result in two parts. I have tried to combine my formula with SPLIT but that didn't work well. How can I do it?

```
={"Faglig vurdering for "& SUM(COUNTIF('Formularsvar 1'!C2:C; "*9M*"))&" elever i 9M";
 QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(IF((LEN('Formularsvar 1'!D2:D))*('Formularsvar 1'!C2:C="9M");
 ('Formularsvar 1'!D2:D&CHAR(10)&
  'Formularsvar 1'!E2:E&CHAR(10)&
  'Formularsvar 1'!F1&" "&'Formularsvar 1'!$F$2:F&" "&
  'Formularsvar 1'!G1&" "&'Formularsvar 1'!$G$2:G&" "&
  'Formularsvar 1'!H1&" "&'Formularsvar 1'!$H$2:H&" "&
  'Formularsvar 1'!$I$2:I&CHAR(10)); ));"where Col1 is not null ORDER BY Col1"; 0)}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this do it?: `=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(IF((LEN('Formularsvar 1'!D2:D))*('Formularsvar 1'!C2:C="9M");ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT('Formularsvar 1'!D2:D&"|||"& 'Formularsvar 1'!E2:E&CHAR(10)& 'Formularsvar 1'!F1&" "&'Formularsvar 1'!$F$2:F&" "& 'Formularsvar 1'!G1&" "&'Formularsvar 1'!$G$2:G&" "& 'Formularsvar 1'!H1&" "&'Formularsvar 1'!$H$2:H&" "& 'Formularsvar 1'!$I$2:I&CHAR(10);"|||"));));"where Col1 is not null ORDER BY Col1";0)`.

Comment: Yes! @Iamblichus, Thank You. It works just like I wanted it to.

Comment: So ;ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(... made the split? And what about "|||"?

Comment: `|||` is just a separator for SPLIT. Could be anything. If that worked, I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136) to separate the two columns. Something like this:

`=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(IF((LEN('Formularsvar 1'!D2:D))*('Formularsvar 1'!C2:C="9M");ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT('Formularsvar 1'!D2:D&"|||"& 'Formularsvar 1'!E2:E&CHAR(10)& 'Formularsvar 1'!F1&" "&'Formularsvar 1'!$F$2:F&" "& 'Formularsvar 1'!G1&" "&'Formularsvar 1'!$G$2:G&" "& 'Formularsvar 1'!H1&" "&'Formularsvar 1'!$H$2:H&" "& 'Formularsvar 1'!$I$2:I&CHAR(10);"|||"));));"where Col1 is not null ORDER BY Col1";0)`

#### Note:

- `|||` here is used as a separator for `SPLIT`. Please replace it with your favorite separator :)